# Android build fail for task app:transformClassesWithDexForQaDebug with java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android, gradle, concurrency, android-emulator

I am stuck with the above mentioned issue. I face this issue while building in CI server which is an AWS Linux machine. The interesting thing is that the Job fails only when the Android Emulator is running in the background. I am running an ARM based Emulator headless.

I have tried all the other solutions mentioned for similar questions. Tried the jvmargs in gradle.properties, Multidex is set to True and javaMaxHeapSize is set to 4g. I still see the error.

Please find the stack trace below.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForQaDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
- Try:
  Run with --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForQaDebug'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
  at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
  at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
  at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
  at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
  at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:54)
  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:158)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
  at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
  ... 57 more
  Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:443)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:178)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:174)
  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
  ... 65 more
  Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
  at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.dexOutOfProcess(DexByteCodeConverter.java:210)
  at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.runDexer(DexByteCodeConverter.java:159)
  at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.convertByteCode(DexByteCodeConverter.java:146)
  at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1422)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:272)
  ... 68 more
  Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
  at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.dexOutOfProcess(DexByteCodeConverter.java:206)
  ... 72 more
  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
  at com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessInfoBuilder$JavaProcessInfoImpl.getExecutable(ProcessInfoBuilder.java:349)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
  at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.lambda$dexOutOfProcess$1(DexByteCodeConverter.java:196)